# Unity C# let code randomly choose between 2 outcomes

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, random

When my enemy dies I am using this to play the dead animation:

```
transform.GetChild(0).GetComponent<Animator>().Play("Death_01");
```

I want to let the code pick between "Death_01"or"Death_02".

What would be the easyest way for doing this? (Array, random number, OR,..)

Comment: well at some point you need a random generator if you want it to be random, right?

Comment: true but I wonder if there is a way to simple say "do this or this". so the code would randomly choose one of these outcomes.

Comment: There is no "randomly execute one of the following lines of code"-operator. You have to use random number generators for this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use Unity's [`Random.Range`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Random.Range.html) to do this.

```
int rand = Random.Range(0, 2);
if (rand == 0)
{
    transform.GetChild(0).GetComponent<Animator>().Play("Death_01");
}

if (rand == 1)
{
    transform.GetChild(0).GetComponent<Animator>().Play("Death_02");
}
```

**EDIT:**

> What would be the easyest way for doing this? (Array, random number,
>   OR,..)

If you have more than 2 animations, you can use a combination of array and `Random.Range`. This makes it more robust instead of using buch of `if` statements.

//Declare the animation array as a global variable somewhere

```
string[] allAnimation = { "Death_01", "Death_02", "Death_03", "Death_04", "Death_05", "Death_06" };
```

Now, you can do:

```
int rand = Random.Range(0, allAnimation.Length);
string animToPlay = allAnimation[rand];
transform.GetChild(0).GetComponent<Animator>().Play(animToPlay);
```

Comment: but the enemys are dieing at a large rate.. would the random not give a problem ?

Comment: No. It will work just like that. No matter how many objects you have.

Comment: Unless if a lot of enemies dies in less than a second

Comment: About how many per frame do you think can slow down a whole game when `Random.Range` is used?

Comment: It's not about slowing the game down. Random typically uses a time based seed. If many enemies die in less than a second, the same "random" number will be generated.

Comment: ok they wont die as fast and if random keeps generating the same number it will still be ok as.

Comment: @MattRowland normally true, but [`UnityEngine.Random.Range`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Random.Range.html) does not do that. It uses a single static random instance for the entire program, you only need to worry about time seeds if you are creating new `System.Random` objects. ShadowMan, you don't need to worry about the problem Matt and Thomas are talking about, they are not talking about Unity's class named `Random` like Programmer and I are but instead are talking about .NET's class named `Random`

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Thanks for clearing that up so as to not confuse OP and other people.